# Serial loop issue on Arduino Leonardo

Tags: loops, serial-port, arduino

Can I have Serial and Serial1 working at the same time?

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);    // While not open, do nothing
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {  // If at least one character is available
    /* CODE */
    //Serial.write(Serial.read());
  }

  while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    /* CODE */
    //Serial.write(Serial1.read());
  }
}
```

When I open the Serial Monitor, the first while it works good, but if I have both, the second one is printing results in an endless loop. How can I solve this?

> The Arduino Leonardo board uses Serial1 to communicate via RS232 on pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX). Serial is reserved for USB CDC communication.

Can I use `Serial1` exactly like `Serial`? What kind of signals are read on *Serial1*?

Comment: you didn't do `while (!Serial1);`

Comment: didn't solve, serial1 keeps in loop

Comment: Is the lower one really `Serial.write`, too? Not `Serial1.write`?

Comment: The OP has left the building ("Last seen more than 3 years ago"), so we will not know what the external input for the second serial port (Arduino digital port DO, RX, 'Serial1') was connected to, if any. But it probably wasn't connected to anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to guess here, but I think that the reason is that there's nothing connected to Serial1 that consumes the data you write. Therefore, your code is stuck in the `write` call.

To verify whether this is indeed the case, you could change `Serial1.write(Serial1.read());` (in the second loop) to `Serial.write(Serial1.read());`. If this doesn't block, my guess was probably right.

*[Getting Started with the Arduino Leonardo, Leonardo ETH and Micro](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoLeonardo#toc6)*  says what Serial1 is:

> To use the hardware serial port (pins 0 and 1, RX and TX), use Serial1. (See the Serial reference pages for more information.)

So, use Serial1 when you want to communicate over the RX and TX ports / 0 and 1 pins that you can see in the corner of the board.

Comment: In fact there's nothing connected to Serial1. Can I link a LED or something else to make some tests?